# reading entire encoded URI in servlet

Tags: javascript

I have a URL like `https://<domainname>/popup.jsp?sitekey=7-8&type=popup`
of this the request parameter string (sitekey=7-8&type=popup) is formed dynamically and then appended to the request URL and then a AJAX request is submitted.
Before attaching the request parameter string to the URL we use escape() function of JS.
so its like :

```
var URL=/popup.jsp?;
var reqVal="sitekey=7-8";
reqVal=reqVal+"&type=popup";
URL=URL+escape(reqVal);
```

So the URL actually is submitted as

```
/popup.jsp?sitekey%3D7-8;amp&type%3Dpopup
```

In servlet when loop through the request parameter names I get parameter name as sitekey%3D7-8  instead of only sitekey and hence my code breaks when I try to get value of sitekey by using request.getParameter("sitekey")

Please help as to how I decode the URL so that request parameter name I get is proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `escape` use `encodeURI`.

**The escape() function was deprecated in JavaScript version 1.5.**

What is the difference?

`escape` — broken, deprecated, do not use, encodes all the characters.

`encodeURI` — encodes characters that are not allowed (raw) in URLs (use it to fix up broken URIs if you can't fix them beforehand)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will use encodeURI but my question is when I encode the entire URI whose result is /popup.jsp?sitekey%3D7-8;amp&type%3Dpopup how am I going to read the request parameters because when i read the request parameter names in servlet I get parameter name as sitekey%3D7-8;amp&type%3D instead of getting sitekey and type as two different parameter names or do you mean to say that encodeURI will encode only the param values and not the param names

Comment: @Mukesh, when you will use `encodeURI` the `?` and `=` won't encode, as they are URL safe chars. So the key will be `sitekey` only.

Comment: I got it.Thanks for the your help.